# Rebar: compiling only project files (without dependencies)

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm new to Erlang and Rebar and just created my first rebar project.

My development cycle looks like that:

1. Edit project files
2. Invoke `rebar compile` to recompile project
3. Run my start.bat file to run and test my application
4. Go to step 1 :-)

The problem is that `rebar compile` seem to always compile both project files and all the dependencies. And I already have quite a bit of dependencies so compilation takes quite long and slows me down.

So the question is: is there a way to tell rebar to compile only my project files during `rebar compile` (but still have dependencies visible for my compiled files)? My dependencies never change so why do I need to recompile them every time?

Or maybe my whole process is utterly wrong and I should take different approach to my development cycle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rebar has a `skip_deps` flag.
So you can compile with `rebar compile skip_deps=true`

Comment: Is it documented anywhere?